Entity Framework Core: Cannot scaffold sqlite database with spatialite (Microsoft.Data.Sqlite.SqliteException) VirtualKNN2
I created sqlite database from geography markup language (gml) file using GDAL GMLAS https://gdal.org/en/latest/drivers/vector/gmlas.html, with command ogr2ogr -f SQLite test.sqlite3 GMLAS:C:\file.gml -dsco SPATIALITE=YES -nlt CONVERT_TO_LINEAR -oo EXPOSE_METADATA_LAYERS=YES
and while trying to scaffold Scaffold-DbContext "Data Source=C:\dev\test3.sqlite3" Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Sqlite -OutputDir Models in entity framework the issue with spatial data occurs Microsoft.Data.Sqlite.SqliteException (0x80004005): SQLite Error 1: 'no such module: VirtualKNN2'.
I tried to work around Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Sqlite.NetTopologySuite and SQLite3Provider_dynamic_cdecl but with no success. Facing You need to call SQLitePCL.raw.SetProvider().  If you are using a bundle package, this is done by calling SQLitePCL.Batteries.Init(). I assume this is because of Database First Approach. It's mentioned here https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/data/sqlite/custom-versions?tabs=net-cli that u need to configure SQLite3Provider before Microsoft.Data.Sqlite is used in your app, and Microsoft.Data.Sqlite is used while scaffolding. So the question is how to scaffold spatial sqlite database properly?

using sqlite3.exe connecting to database and then loading mod_spatialite
with SELECT load_extension(mod_spatialite);
and droping KNN2 table with DROP TABLE KNN2; allowed me to scaffold.
I assume before scaffolding it's neaceasery to load_extension (but how to do this)
